# Delete using case statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to delete rows on the basis of their id. For multiple tables I want to generate a single query that will accept the table name and id and perform the operation.

Now the scenario is that, I don't want to use if - else statement. I want to use case statement to detect the table name perform the function.

Please help me.

Comment: You can't. Case is used in a query not to control the flow of execution and the table name can't be parametrised or assigned dynamically from a name in a variable/parameter (without building up the whole string and using dynamic SQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As been mentioned by Martin, you can't directly but you could write a stored procedure to perform the delete.

Comparing

```
EXEC SLOW_DELETE 'TestTable', 1
```

with

```
DELETE FROM TestTable WHERE ID = 1
```

is not a huge difference though (besides being a performance drain).

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SLOW_DELETE(@TableName sysname, @ID INT) AS 
BEGIN

  IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.tables WHERE name=@TableName) <> 1)
  BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Ambiguous or non existent table name passed %s',16,1,@TableName)
  RETURN
  END

  DECLARE @Stmt nvarchar(500)
  SET @Stmt = 'DELETE FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' WHERE ID = @ID'

  EXEC sp_executesql @Stmt, N'@ID INT', @ID = @ID
END
```

I wonder what you hope to gain from using such an approach. Perhaps if you expand on your motives, we could suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: Ouch! `@TableName` should be `sysname`. Variable type should be `nvarchar`. `quote_name` should be used and `sp_executesql` with `@Id` passed as a parameter. (To reduce SQL injection possibilities as well as coping with object names that aren't just straightforward alphanumeric)

Comment: @Martin, ouch indeed. I have tried to adress your (valid) concerns. Should you notice any other blatant mistakes, I'm sure you'll mention them :)

Comment: That edit still wouldn't work. I took the liberty of editing your answer feel free to roll it back if you don't like it!

Comment: Thanks Martin. Besides the missing QUOTENAME, it should be possible to have 2 parameters (as in my original edit) isn't it? I found it a bit easier to read.

Comment: The table name can't be parameterised. That bit always needs to be done through string concatenation (and you can't do the concatenation inline in the parameter list of the procedure call itself)